# Kibana for showing analytics to end user

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

We have a hosted analytics tool, in this we store data to mongodb, push data to ElasticSearch, do analytics on it and shows charts to end user. Can you guys guide me that How can I use kibana in this use case to show charts to end user? because I saw Kibana is complete client side and it send query directly to ElasticSearch that's mean Kibana require username/password on client browser's and that is not secure way.

<del>My question is it possible to use Kibana to show analytics charts to end user?</del>

After [Nick Zadrozny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/154694/nick-zadrozny)'s comment I changed question to

**Can Kibana be used to (securely) show charts to end users?**

Another thing is that Can I integrate it to my own application without kibana's layout.

Comment: I think there's an interesting question in here, but it could probably be better posed. "Can Kibana be used to (securely) show charts to end users?" Perhaps also, "What are good tools to show charts and analytics to end users based on data stored in Elasticsearch?" Certainly I'd love to know the answers to those.

Comment: maybe this helps: https://github.com/salyh/elastic-defender

Answer (score 1):

There are people who have built up complicated nginx rules to try and keep kibana users from screwing up elasticsearch.

Kibana4, being a server-side binary, offers more hopes in the regard.

Also, they're planning to release "[shield](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/shield-know-security-coming-soon/)" sometime soon, which promises access control, etc.